# How to assign a user friendly email address to a document library

Tags: email, document-library

I have a document library which is configured for inbound emails. The current email address assigned is `List@SharepointServername`.

I need to somehow map a generic email ID (say `abcd@mycompany.com`) to this list so that when I send out a mail to abcd@mycompany.com it goes in the document library.

Any help/pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am not the email expert, and this might sound like a dummy solution, but I would configure a rule in your email server to forward every email from abcd@mycompany.com to abcd@sharepoint.

SharePoint can also read emails from Dump folder, so if you can "dump" your emails from your email server to a folder on SharePoint server in EML format that would could also work.

**UPDATE**: For both approaches the email (To) must be the same as specified in Document Library settings. Otherwise it will not be imported to Document Library. (by Alex)

Comment: That should work. The key thing is that the e-mail address within the message must match the e-mail address of the document library. Otherwise SharePoint will toss it away.

Comment: Yup, you are correct! Will update the answer.